# What does this Python line mean?

Tags: python

I came across this line in a Python code and don't know how what it does:

```
do_update = error !=0
```

This was the context, the code was a perceptron classifier:

```
    def update(self, instance):
    """
    Perform perceptron update, if the wrong label is predicted.
    Return a boolean value indicating whether an update was performed.
    """
    error = 0
    predicted_output = self.prediction(instance.feature_counts)
    if(predicted_output==True and instance.label==False):error = 1
    if(predicted_output==False and instance.label==True):error = -1

    do_update = error !=0

    if do_update:
        for feature, count in instance.feature_counts.items():
            self.weights[feature] += error*count
    return do_update
```

Can someone explain how it works?

Comment: It assigns a boolean value to `do_update` variable. If `error != 0`, `do_update` will be `True`, `False` otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`do_update = error !=0`

Means: evaluate `error !=0` and assign the result to `do_update`.

The evaluation of `error !=0` will be a boolean (True / False), based on the value of `error`.

Specifically:

if `error` equals `0`, `do_update` will be `False`

if `error` is not equal `0`, `do_update` will be `True`

Answer (score 0):

This is a quick way to store the result of a check.

Because `error != 0` returns bool, `do_update` is `False` or `True`.

Bascially, if error is 0, do_update is False, else do_update is True.

Answer (score 0):

`error !=0` is a Boolean expression and will return `True` if `error` does not hold the value `0`, and `False` otherwise. It might help to add brackets:

```
do_update = (error != 0)
```